# Plotting data from a text file on the desktop

Tags: monitoring, conky

I want to monitor some simulations I run In a way similar to how text monitor display data. I can easily generate a bunch of text files or image files with the data/plot I want to follow. How can I display them as a part of my desktop background in an eye-pleasing way? I tried conky but I couldn't get it to display image. For example, following conky's wiki I have set up this:

```
TEXT
${image /home/yotam/Downloads/images.jpg -p 20,20 -s 200x200}${image /home/yotam/Downloads/images.jpg -p 20,240 -s 200x200}${image /home/yotam/Downloads/images.jpg -p 20,460 -s 200x200}
```

And now nothing is displayed.

Comment: It is hard to follow what you are trying to do. Maybe `xplot` is worth checking out?

Comment: The simplest way I can describe this is: "I want to generate an applet that will plot some data files which change over time. I look for system monitor plots for inspiration."

Comment: "generate an applet" = write a program? That program must access the text files and present the data as GFX. I don't know of any "system monitor plots", though.

Comment: I was hoping to change and existing one but yes, essentially write a program.

Comment: Oh, conky is a very good approach, however only if you know about LUA scripting. You might want to check out the forum at http://crunchbang.org , where some utter wizards have managed to get diagrams displayed on conky. Note that this will absolutely require conky to be compiled with the __cairo bindings__ since `cairo` will be responsible for all the graphical stuff. Perhaps you could go cutting and pasting some sample code snippets from there and advance in your "quest" that way?